# Setting double value to NULL in Database using Delphi / FireDac

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am reading and writing data into an Microsoft Access database using Delphi 11.2 and FireDac.
I'd like to be able to set numeric values in the database to NULL based on the (double) value in delphi.
I am currently reading values as strings from the DB

```
myQuery.FieldByName('myNumericField').AsString
```

into my delphi object fields and set double values on application level to NAN if I find empty strings. When I write them back to the DB and the user has not set the value on application level the value is obviously set to NAN in the DB as well, but not to NULL, which would be preferred.

Does anybody know a feasible way to set double / numeric fields to NULL in an (microsoft Access or presumably any other) database via firedac?

Help is much appreciated!

Simplified code samples for update and insert I am currently using

update:

```
dbMain.ExecSQL('update MyTable set ' + 'myNumericField = :P1 ' + 'where myIDField = :P2', [myDataObject.myDoubleValue, myDataObject.myId]);
```

insert:

```
 dbMain.ExecSQL
      ('insert into MyTable(myIDField, myNumericField) '
      + 'values(:P1, :P2)',
      [myDataObject.myId, myDataObject.myDoubleValue]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```pascal
var
  varValue: Variant;

if IsNan(myDataObject.myDoubleValue) then
  varValue := Null
else
  varValue := myDataObject.myDoubleValue;

dbMain.ExecSQL('update MyTable set myNumericField = :P1 where myIDField = :P2', [varValue, myDataObject.myId]);
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
if IsNan(myDataObject.myDoubleValue) then
  dbMain.ExecSQL('update MyTable set myNumericField = NULL where myIDField = :P1', [myDataObject.myId])
else
  dbMain.ExecSQL('update MyTable set myNumericField = :P1 where myIDField = :P2', [myDataObject.myDoubleValue, myDataObject.myId]);
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
var
  Params: TFDParams;
  Param: TFDParam;

Params := TFDParams.Create;
try

  Param := Params.Add('P1', ftFloat);
  if IsNan(myDataObject.myDoubleValue) then
  begin
    Param.Bound := True;
    Param.Clear;
  end else
    Param.Value := myDataObject.myDoubleValue;

  Params.Add('P2', myDataObject.myId);

  dbMain.ExecSQL('update MyTable set myNumericField = :P1 where myIDField = :P2', Params);
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Hey @Remy Lebeau,
thanks a lot! That was tremendous help! I went for the third alternative. On the first one, I got complaints when setting Null, that I have to specify the data type of the parameter. The third one was quite a change in my app, because I have various fields (10+) in about 5 tables, for whom I need the behavior. But it worked out well and appears to be a very clean way of handling it, because I don't need to execute additional db queries for achieving it.

Comment: One thing hindered me a bit, which I was not aware of yet. It appears that I need to add the parameters to the tfd params object in the same order in which I put the parameters in my query in the execsql call. The parameter names ('P1' etc) don't seem to matter. I came accross the issue, because I wanted to reuse the TFDParams object for my insert and my update statements and it didn't work out for that reason - at least that's my current analysis to it.
Either way thanks a lot!